# Basic Combinatorics/Probability Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say we are dealt 5 cards from a well-shuffled pack. What is the probability of the hand containing exactly 3 kings?

My reasoning is: $$\frac{4 \choose 3}{52 \choose 5}$$

However, something in the back of my head is bugging me about the other two cards in the hand, which could be anything (other than a king). So we'd get something like: $$\frac{{4 \choose 3}\times{48 \choose 2}}{52 \choose 5}$$

Sorry for the straightforward question, but I've never had much of an intuition for combinatorics :P Could someone set me straight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to count the number of combinations that have exactly three kings. Not at least three kings.

First the ways of obtaining kings are: $\binom{4}{3}$, and the way to obtaining the other two cards not to be kings is $\binom{48}{2}$. You divide this by the total number of combinations you can be dealt, which is $\binom{52}{5}$. So your second answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

A more pedantic approach:

Let $K_i$ be the event that a king was selected on the $i$th draw from the pack, and $\overline{K_i}$ the complement.

First compute the probability of $K_1 K_2 K_3 \overline{K_4} \overline{K_5}$ as
$ \frac{4}{52} \frac{3}{51} \frac{2}{50} \frac{48}{49} \frac{47}{48}  = \frac{4!\,48!\,47!}{1! \, 52! \, 46!}$.

Then notice that the probability will be the same regardless of where the three $K_i$ events occur (the positions in the numerator will change, but the same numbers appear, just in a different order). For example, the probability of 
$K_1  \overline{K_2} K_3 \overline{K_4} K_5$ is $ \frac{4}{52} \frac{48}{51} \frac{3}{50} \frac{47}{49} \frac{2}{48}  = \frac{4!\,48!\,47!}{1! \, 52! \, 46!}$, which is the same as above.

We see that there are $\binom{5}{3}$ ways of exactly three $K_i$ events occurring in a 5 card draw.

Hence the probability is $\binom{5}{3} \frac{4!\,48!\,47!}{1! \, 52! \, 46!} = \frac{5!}{3!\,2!} \frac{4!\,48!\,47!}{1! \, 52! \, 46!} = \frac{5!\, 47!}{52!}  \frac{4!}{1!\,3!} \frac{48!}{2!\,46!} = \frac{\binom{4}{3} \binom{48}{2}}{\binom{52}{5}}$.

Comment: I really like this way of thinking about it, thanks for taking the time. I've never had much intuition for combinatorics because I don't know how to justify calculations to myself besides trying out small examples.

Comment: @snarski: I have been dealing with probability for 35 years, and still make frequent egregious mistakes. Good luck!

Comment: Likewise, my thanks :) This is a nice derivation; the conceptual similarity to the binomial distribution (but with variable probabilities) makes it much more clear *why* this is the answer.